# One line user input assignment in C++

Tags: c++, string, cin

I am learning C++ and was wondering if there is an equivalent to assigning a user input to a variable in one line, like you can do in C# for example:

`string foo = Console.ReadLine();`

I was hoping that one of these would work, but they don't.

`const string foo = cin >> foo;`

`cin >> const string foo;`

Ideally the variable should be a constant, but that's not necessarily a requirement.

Are there ways of one lining it in C++ or will I just have to learn to live with this?

```
double foo = 0;
cin >> foo;
```

Comment: a double line would be the only way to go. You must declare the variable before it is used. :/

Comment: you can always write the function yourself.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to write it in one line, like this: `double foo = 0;
cin >> foo;`. Whether declarations/statements are on the same line or not generally has no meaning to the compiler.

Comment: It is also possible in a single declaration: `double foo = ( cin >> foo, foo );`, using the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). However, I don't recommend doing that.

Comment: not always pushing too much into a single line helps for clarity and readability. You can write a function, but then make the function work with any input stream, add io manipulators, enable reading multiple values in one expression, and suddenly the function becomes a complicated mess. Of course io in C++ could look completely different, but it doesnt ;)

Comment: You can do `double foo = *std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin)`

Answer (score 2):

As apple apple says you can write your own functions

```
double console_read_double()
{
    double x = 0.0;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    double y = console_read_double();
    double z = console_read_double();
    ...
}
```

However one advantage of the C++ way is that you can *chain* calls to input functions

```
int main()
{
    double y, z;
    cin >> y >> z;
    ...
}
```

You can't do that with a function call that returns the value read.

Another advantage is that you can test the success or failure of the operation with a single line of code

```
int main()
{
    double y, z;
    if (cin >> y >> z)
    {
        // success
    }
    else
    {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there is no way in C++ to do this in one line. Unless you do this when you are using an if statement:

```
if(double b = 0; std::cin >> b)
{
  // Code
}
```

otherwise you will have to live with:

```
double b = 0;
std::cin >> b;
```

Or you can just make a function like this:

```
auto init_and_input()
{
  double b = 0;
  std::cin >> b;
  return b;
}
```

and then:

```
int main()
{
  auto x = init_and_input();
}
```

**So your answer is not really if you include the function.**

Comment: `double b = 0; std::cin >> b;` is one line

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been stated, and in the ultra specific scenario where you need to get only one character, standard library provide the function [get()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) that reads and return **one** character in a stream. This allows you to initialize your variable with the read value, therefore you could also define it as a `const`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   const char some_char = std::cin.get();
   // Do whatever with some_char
   return 0;
}
```

Note that even if it is theoretically valid C++, this doesn't looks like any kind of good practice, and it might be preferable in almost every case to just stick to another, most common, way to read your stream.

Comment: To be fair, I can't think of any use case where this could be the way to do, but as the STL provide it, I felt like it would be a good thing to state it